# Mixed Content err when deploying

Tags: firebase, google-maps, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a project and wanted to host my dev server to firebase hosting.

When I deployed the app, I received a few Mixed Content errors in chrome dev tools saying I needed to switch a few source files from http to https, which I did. This is the entire error message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://peer-program-atx.firebaseapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

One of those that I needed to edit was for the Google Maps API. I searched through the entire project to find any instances of `'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'` so that I could switch it to the https protocol.

After doing this, I continue to receive the exact same error in Chrome dev tools which is preventing the page from loading. Is that expected behavior or must I figure out why my edit to the Google Maps source did not fix the issue?

If I must fix this issue in order to fully render the web page, how can I fix this?

My entire project can be found here: https://github.com/SIeep/peer-program-atx

My project is currently hosted here: https://peer-program-atx.firebaseapp.com

Any help or ideas is welcomed and appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it looks like it's working now. Strange. I must've been impatient or something. Cool beans!